# Как создать N-е количество кнопок в андроид

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Не могу создать массив кнопок Android Studio не пропускает такой код:

```
for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
    Button btn[i] = new Button(this);
    btn[i].setText("кнопка " + i);
    btn[i].setId(i);
}
```

Comment: Что значит "не пропускает"? Что за ошибка? `this` - это ссылка на что? Вы это где-то в коде вашей `Activity` делаете?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Во-первых, так писать нельзя `Button btn[i] = new Button(this);`.

Во-вторых, ваш код ничего не делает в целом, так как вы эту кнопку ни к чему не прикрепили.

В-третьих, кнопке нужно задать параметры.

То есть, должно быть что-то вроде такого:

```
Button[] btn = new Button[3];
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
    btn[i] = new Button(this);
    btn[i].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    btn[i].setText("кнопка " + i);
    btn[i].setId(i);

    // слой, к которому кнопку хотите прикрепить
    layout.addView(btn[i]);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, все работает)

Comment: @Samsonin не за что (: Отметьте вопрос как принятый, если помогло.

Comment: подскажите куда нажать?

Comment: @Samsonin галочка слева от ответа.

Answer (score 1):

По своему обыкновению дополню принятый ответ. В ответе все прекрасно кроме кусочка:

```
btn[i].setId(i);
```

Это нерабочий код, нельзя просто так взять и присвоить `id` вьюшке :)

Есть специальный метод для программной генерации идентификатора:

```
int id=View.generateViewId();
btn[i].setId(id);
```

Comment: Спасибо за совет